# index error in database reading PHP script

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

So Im back with another php error, that I cant solve. But Im getting better:)

I have created a simple script that stores images in a database, I have no problems to store the file, but when Im reading the file i get an index error. It says

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\gallery2\show.php on line
>   13

I cant really get what the problem is since Im thinking that everything is correct !?

the code for showing the images are

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "guestbook";


@mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$id = $_GET['id'];

if(!isset($id) || empty($id)){
die("Please select your image!");
}else{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE id='".$id."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $content;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `$_GET['id']`. However, if no argument `id` is present in the [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of the request, the index `id` will not be available in the `$_GET` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). That's why you receive the notice.

So you should be doing something like this:

```
$id = !empty( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'id' ] : null;
```

Comment: That helped me to ge rid of the error, but I cant accualy read from the database. do you have a clue how to displat the images in the database ? thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you the value id does not exist in the $_GET array. Does the URL you are accessing have a ?id=something on it?

Answer (score 0):

The variable...

```
$_GET['id'];
```

...doesn't contain a value, therefore it is not defined.

Check if your form mechanism leading to this `$_GET` is working, maybe `var_dump` it.

If your script should cope with an empty variable there, maybe check this variable first, something like this:

```
 $id = "";
 if (isset($_GET['id']) { $id = $_GET['id']; }
```